# How to create Tabs using AngularJs and Bootstrap - Need to modify existing code

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have found on stackoverflow a good example of how to create Tabs using AngularJS and Bootstrap, but I have a problem. The original code is using an old library of Angular (1.0.4) and if I switch to the current one (1.4.7) the script does not work anymore.

Here is the original [code on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fuVb0mzhmDCKr1xKp7Rn?p=preview)

Here is the [original Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872191/angularjs-ui-bootstrap-tabs-that-support-routing)

> Here is what I've tried so far to change:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
      .when('/jobs', {
        templateUrl: 'jobs-partial.html',   
        controller: JobsCtrl
      })
      .when('/invoices', {
        templateUrl: 'invoices-partial.html',   
        controller: InvoicesCtrl
      })
      .when('/payments', {
        templateUrl: 'payments-partial.html',   
        controller: PaymentsCtrl
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/jobs'
      });
});
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of AngularJS 1.2 and later:

> [`ngRoute` is now its own module](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#ngroute-has-been-moved-into-its-own-module)

As of AngularJS 1.3 and later:

> ...`$controller` will no longer look for controllers on window. The old behavior of looking on window for controllers was originally intended for use in examples, demos, and toy apps. We found that allowing global controller functions encouraged poor practices, so we resolved to disable this behavior by default.

Therefore [1] adding `ngRoute` as a dependency to your module and [2] including the `angular-route.js` source file and [3] explicitly registering the controllers fixed it for me:

http://plnkr.co/edit/KJyFqf2vf74IidY26vxu?p=preview

[1]

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngRoute']);
```

[2]

```
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular-route.js"></script>
```

[3]

```
app.controller('TabsCtrl', TabsCtrl);
app.controller('JobsCtrl', JobsCtrl);
app.controller('InvoicesCtrl', InvoicesCtrl);
app.controller('PaymentsCtrl', PaymentsCtrl);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can you explain why do I need to explicitly registering the controllers? Why did not need it before?

Comment: @ElviraEmm You're welcome!  Yes I can explain: you need to explicitly register them because they dropped support in 1.3.  I've updated my answer with a quote from their site.

Answer (score 2):

Older versions of angular allowed for the use of global functions as controllers.

Support for that was dropped in version 1.3 and you need to register controllers as a module component.

Also `ngRoute` is a separate include now and must be injected as a module dependency

Here's an updated demo using angular 1.4.

Note that controllers are registered using:

```
angular.module('plunker')
.controller('TabsCtrl',TabsCtrl)
.controller('InvoicesCtrl',InvoicesCtrl)
.controller('PaymentsCtrl',PaymentsCtrl)
```

And in routing the controller is now  string. Also `ngRoute` is included as module dependency

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
      when('/jobs', {templateUrl: 'jobs-partial.html',   controller: 'JobsCtrl' }).
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/pETPV1cBrw9HrtQ41EOx?p=preview)**</kbd>